# wget won't download files I can access through browser

Tags: web-scraping, wget

I am an amateur historian trying to access newspaper archives. The server where the scans are located "works" using an outdated tif viewer that doesn't seem to actually work at all anymore. I can access the files individually in chrome without logging in, but when I try to use wget or curl, I'm told that viewing the file is unauthorized, even when I use my login info, and even when using my cookies from chrome.

Here is an example of one of the files: https://ulib.aub.edu.lb/nahar/images2/7810W2/78101001.TIF

When I put this into chrome, it automatically downloads the file even though I cannot access the directory itself, but when I use wget, I get the following response: "401 unauthorized Username/Password Authentication Failed."

This is the basic wget command I'm using (if I can get it to work at all, then I'll input a list of the other files):

```css
wget --no-check-certificate https://ulib.aub.edu.lb/nahar/images2/7810W2/78101001.TIF
```

I've tried variations with and without cookies, with a blank user, with and without login credentials, As I'm sure you can tell, I'm new to this sort of thing but eager to learn.

Answer (score -1):

From what I can see, authentication on your website is done with HTTP basic. This kind of authentication is not using HTTP cookies, it is using HTTP Authorization header. You can pass HTTP basic credentials to `wget` with the following arguments.

```
wget --http-user=YourUsername --http-password=YourPassword https://ulib.aub.edu.lb/nahar/images2/7810W2/78101001.TIF
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, Benoit! I tried using '--user user --password pass' after the URL and for some reason it's working whereas it wasn't when I put it before the URL. Does that make any sense? I'll give it a shot with '--http-user' instead and see if that makes a difference. Thanks again!